# News App using Multiple RSS feed

Tags: android, xml, rss

I am building a simple news app which shows news from a couple of websites in order. I am building a simple activity to show an image from the news and the title from the different RSS feed url.
I want to do like when I am enter any RSS feed url it give text & image url in format. My problem is how can I find image url from Different RSS feed set in image view.
because All RSS feed have different Image Tag so how can we identify & filter Image url.please Help me.

Comment: Hello Anyone use Mercury Api  for clutter website content only get specific content of website.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It depends on how its build the RSS.
First of all you need and RSS Parser like https://github.com/prof18/RSS-Parser (I didn't use this but I think its good)

In my case, I have the option to customize the RSS(Its my page) so I added a HTML img tag in the title of the RSS Item. Then in my application I used JSOUP https://jsoup.org/ to parse the title and grab the src of the img tag.

If you want I can provide you the parser that I use in my application

Regards

Comment: My problem is I parse many RSS feed like TOI,NDTV,BBC news.but in all that feed all gives images but in different ways.. like any tag, inside description tag now how can I filter image tag ... if I add any url its show in format..like text, image

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: I want to make like DailyHunt & NewsPoint..if you know then suggest me.